# How to add COPY FROM STDIN in Elixir Repo.Transaction

Tags: elixir, ecto

I'm experimenting with Elixir Ecto and now I need to realize COPY FROM STDIN in my code. I found example in postgrex.ex on github:

```
Postgrex.transaction(pid, fn(conn) ->
  query = Postgrex.prepare!(conn, "", "COPY posts FROM STDIN",[copy_data:true])
  stream = Postgrex.stream(conn, query, [])
  Enum.into(File.stream!("posts"), stream)
end)
```

How I can convert it for my needs. What pid I have to pass?

```
Repo.transaction fn ->
  query = "some query"
  Ecto.Adapters.SQL.query!(Repo, query, [])
  #copy from stdin, how??
end
```

Answer (score 5):

As per [this post](https://elixirforum.com/t/copy-from-stdin-through-repo/1588/3) by [James Fish](https://elixirforum.com/users/fishcakez) on the Elixir Forum, it should be possible:

> It is possible to run a COPY FROM STDIN using
>   Ecto.Adapters.SQL.query!/4 but can't use a collectable/stream:
>
> ```
> Ecto.Adapters.SQL.query!(Repo, "COPY posts FROM STDIN",
> [data_as_(final)_parameter], [copy_data: true])
> ```

..and:

> From Ecto 2.1 the above no longer works. Instead must use built in
>   streams:
>
> ```
> stream = Ecto.Adapters.SQL.stream(TestRepo, "COPY posts FROM STDIN")
> TestRepo.transaction(fn -> Enum.into(data_enum, stream) end)
> ```

Answer (score 2):

The following worked for me

```
csv_data = "col1,col2\r\n1,1\r\n2,2"

sql = """
COPY my_table (col1, col2)
FROM STDIN
CSV HEADER
"""

steam = SQL.stream(Repo, sql)

Repo.transaction(fn -> Enum.into([csv_data], stream) end)
```

Answer (score 1):

I wasn't able to figure out how to do this with pure Ecto either, but why not use Postgrex? You're probably already using it as an adapter.

Assuming your STDIN will be CSV formatted data:

```
def bulk_update(data_stream, temp_table_query, copy_data_query) do
  opts = MyApp.Repo.config
  {:ok, pid} = Postgrex.start_link(opts)
  Postgrex.transaction(pid, &update_table(&1, data_stream, temp_table_query, copy_data_query))
  GenServer.stop(pid)
end

def update_table(conn, data, create_temp_table, copy_table_data) do
  Postgrex.query(conn, create_temp_table, [])
  query = Postgrex.prepare!(conn, "", "COPY incoming_data FROM STDIN DELIMITER ',' CSV", [copy_data: true])
  stream = Postgrex.stream(conn, query, [])
  Enum.into(data, stream)
  Postgrex.query(conn, copy_table_data, [])
end
```

Comment: It's ok for me to use Postgrex directy, but how do I can get connection from the Repo pool instead starting new connection (your example above)